# How do I make this inline JavaScript external?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am currently working on a music player chrome extension and my HTML is unresponsive. I found that it is because I have inline javascript with my onclick functions.

html:

```
<button id="pre" onclick="prev()"><img src="images/prev.png" height="90%" width="90%"/></button>
            <button id="play" onclick="playOrPauseSong()"><img src="images/play.png"/></button>
            <button id="next" onclick="next()"><img src="images/next.png" height="90%" width="90%"/></button>
```

javascript:

```
function playOrPauseSong(){

if(song.paused)
{
    song.play();
    $("#play img").attr("src","images/pause.png");
}
else
{
    song.pause();
    $("#play img").attr("src","images/play.png");        
}
```

}

I have the same issues for the prev function and the next function of course but they should all have the same solution I assume.

Comment: put the code in a file ... include the file in a script tag ... however, your assumption that the code doesn't work because it is inline is far from correct

Comment: "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution."

Comment: this is the error i was given when inspecting the popup and after looking around i was told that there cant be any inline scripts. also my issue is im not entirely sure how to make the html responsive by making it purely external

Comment: oh, right, well, the error message sheds a new light on your issue

Answer (score 0):

As far as you're already using jQuery (nothing would've changed much if you didn't though), you could enjoy event binding methods provided by jQuery, for example:

HTML:

```
<button id="play">
    <img src="images/play.png"/>
</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#play").on("click", function() {
    if(song.paused) {
        song.play();
        $("#play img").attr("src","images/pause.png");
    }
    else {
        song.pause();
        $("#play img").attr("src","images/play.png");        
    }
}
```

This way, your JavaScript code can be completely separated from HTML markup.

**P.S.**
I would've commented, but don't have enough reputation for that.